# React Router(V6) How to call loader funcition in all routes?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, frontend

Simple question as u can see i have dummy loader function in **Home** route i want to call same loader function in all routes. i do not want to copy paste to all routes is there a elegant way to do that?

````js
const routes = createBrowserRouter([
    {
        path: '*',
        element: <h1>Not found</h1>
    },
    {
        path: '/',
        element: <Home/>,
        loader: function (data) {
            console.log(data)
            return null;
        },
        action: function () {
            console.log('action');
        }
    },
    {
        path: '/contact',
        element: <Contact/>
    },
    {
        path: '/admin',
        children: [
            {path: 'dashboard', element: <Dashboard/>},
            {path: 'manage', element: <Dashboard/>},
            {path: 'manage/user/:userId', element: <Dashboard/>},
            {path: 'settings', element: <Dashboard/>},
        ]
    }
])```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution: Add the `loader` property to route object recursively by a JavaScript function.

```
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
import {
  createBrowserRouter,
  RouterProvider,
  useLoaderData
} from "react-router-dom";

function Home() {
  const data = useLoaderData();
  console.log("home loader data： ", data);
  return <div>home</div>;
}
function Contact() {
  const data = useLoaderData();
  console.log("contact loader data： ", data);
  return <div>contact</div>;
}

function Dashboard() {
  const data = useLoaderData();
  console.log("dashboard loader data： ", data);
  return <div>dashboard</div>;
}

function someLoader() {
  return "some data";
}

function attachLoaderRecursively(routes, loader) {
  for (const route of routes) {
    if (route.path) {
      route.loader = loader;
    }
    if (route.children?.length) {
      attachLoaderRecursively(route.children, loader);
    }
  }
  return routes;
}

const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <Home />
  },
  {
    path: "/contact",
    element: <Contact />
  },
  {
    path: "/admin",
    children: [
      { path: "dashboard", element: <Dashboard /> },
      { path: "manage", element: <div>manage</div> },
      { path: "manage/user/:userId", element: <div>manage user by id</div> },
      { path: "settings", element: <div>settings</div> }
    ]
  }
];

const routesWithLoader = attachLoaderRecursively(routes, someLoader);
console.log(routesWithLoader);
const router = createBrowserRouter(routesWithLoader);

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
const root = createRoot(rootElement);

root.render(<RouterProvider router={router} />);
```

[image]

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-76779427-md9vrx?file=/src/index.js)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the purpose of your loader is, but `useRouteLoaderData()` allows you to access loader data from other routes. Might be worth a look if you want to load the same data (e.g. via a Root/App component) and access it universally.

> This hook makes the data at any currently rendered route available anywhere in the tree. This is useful for components deep in the tree needing data from routes much farther up, as well as parent routes needing the data of child routes deeper in the tree.

https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-route-loader-data